# Pytest - How to pass an argument to setup_class?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some code as shown below.
I am getting a `too few args` error when I run it.
I am not calling `setup_class` explicitly, so not sure how to pass any parameter to it.
I tried decorating the method with `@classmethod`, but still see the same error.

The error that I am seeing is this - `E           TypeError: setup_class() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

One point to note - If I do not pass any parameter to the class, and pass only `cls`, then I am not seeing the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I did review these questions [question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736363/pytest-how-to-pass-a-class-parameter-to-setup-class) and [question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538808/pytest-2-3-adding-teardowns-within-the-class)prior to posting. I did not understand the solutions posted to these questions, or how they would work.

```
class A_Helper:
    def __init__(self, fixture):
        print "In class A_Helper"

    def some_method_in_a_helper(self):
        print "foo"

class Test_class:
    def setup_class(cls, fixture):
        print "!!! In setup class !!!"
        cls.a_helper = A_Helper(fixture)

    def test_some_method(self):
        self.a_helper.some_method_in_a_helper()
        assert 0 == 0
```

Comment: @metatoaster I should not have to instantiate `Test_class`. I am expecting `A_Helper` to be instantiated using the `arg` that I supply. And then using that object (`a_helper`), I am hoping to invoke the method in `A_Helper`. Am I conceptually missing something? Same code works, without having to instantiate anything, as long as I do not provide an arg to the `setup_class`.

Comment: As pointed out by @metatoaster it can't be done. But wouldn't it be simplier to define `a_helper` fixture (with `scope='class'`) and pass it to `test_some_method`? Generally `setup_class` handling is added to py.test only to make it compatible with classical unit-style testing. I advice not to mix these two things (i.e. classical style with py.test fixture style).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get this error because you are trying to mix two independent testing styles that py.test supports: the classical unit testing and pytest's fixtures.

What I suggest is not to mix them and instead simply define a class scoped fixture like this:

```
import pytest

class A_Helper:
    def __init__(self, fixture):
        print "In class A_Helper"

    def some_method_in_a_helper(self):
        print "foo"

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def a_helper(fixture):
    return A_Helper(fixture)

class Test_class:
    def test_some_method(self, a_helper):
        a_helper.some_method_in_a_helper()
        assert 0 == 0
```

Comment: Hi, I wish to use your approach but in addition of using the fixture inside the test function, pass it also to prolog function like `setup_class` or `setup_method`. Perhaps you can extend your example to add this functionality ? Thanks !

Comment: This means that referenced fixture `fixture` should also be scoped as `class`, which is a nightmare.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using this with pytest, it will only call `setup_class` with one argument and one argument only, doesn't look like you can change this without changing how [pytest calls this](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/src/fa62c5c63c2fb5870852676d8d8899b9656214fd/_pytest/python.py?at=default#cl-540).

You should just follow the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#class-level-setup-teardown) and define the `setup_class` function as specified and then set up your class inside that method with your custom arguments that you need inside that function, which would look something like

```
class Test_class:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print "!!! In setup class !!!"
        arg = '' # your parameter here
        cls.a_helper = A_Helper(arg)

    def test_some_method(self):
        self.a_helper.some_method_in_a_helper()
        assert 0 == 0
```

Comment: I edited the question, and replaced `arg` with `fixture`. My intent is - **from** the test method, I want to pass one or more fixtures **to** a helper method, and do some action with the `fixture` in the helper method. If passing a second arg is not possible, then I am not sure how I would pass a fixture, even in the body of the method.

Comment: One comment in the documentation is pretty interesting, specifically under the _Remarks_ section at the end: _Now the xunit-style functions are integrated with the fixture mechanism and obey the proper scope rules of fixtures involved in the call._ I wonder if this broke that "mixing" technique that @freakish mentioned in the other answer which may have previously worked when the scope rules weren't obeyed.