# Pytest how to include "setup" fixture with scope "class"

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using pytest and usually group my tests as "mirror" of the modules in my package. To have a good structure inside my test module I like to then group some tests in classes even though I am using pytest. I´ve run into a problem with scope levels of fixtures. Consider this minimal example:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixture_a():
    return 2


class TestExample:
    b = 1.

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
    def add_info(self, fixture_a):
        self.c = self.b * fixture_a

    def test_foo(self):
        assert self.c + self.b == 3

    def test_bar(self):
        assert self.c * self.b == 2
```

This works however 'setup' is executed twice i.e. once for each test method. I would like it to be executed only once per class instance but when changing the fixtures scope to 'class' I get:

```
FAILED                        [ 50%]
tests\tests_simple\test_library\test_example_sof.py:15 (TestExample.test_foo)
self = <test_example_sof.TestExample object at 0x0000019A8C9C9CC0>

    def test_foo(self):
>       assert self.c + self.b == 3
E       AttributeError: 'TestExample' object has no attribute 'c'

test_example_sof.py:17: AttributeError
FAILED                        [100%]
tests\tests_simple\test_library\test_example_sof.py:18 (TestExample.test_bar)
self = <test_example_sof.TestExample object at 0x0000019A8C9C9EF0>

    def test_bar(self):
>       assert self.c * self.b == 2
E       AttributeError: 'TestExample' object has no attribute 'c'

test_example_sof.py:20: AttributeError

Assertion failed
```

So it seems as if setup is not run at all anymore. Could somebody explain why and offer a solution?

Comment: I’m not familiar with @pytest.fixture. Is it not redundant for setup. What happens when you remove it from setup?

Comment: in that case it is seen as a classmethod. However it does not accept the other fixture (fixture_a) from the module as input. I´ve read that using pytest together with a setup method does not allow for any additional arguments to be passed to the setup method. However this i necessary in my case as I need to access the fixture outside the class (fixture_a). "setup" was a bad name here I should have named it differently to avoid confusion. Will edit the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't assign to test instance attributes in a class-scoped fixture. As long as `setup` is a function-scoped fixture, everything is fine because it is executed for each `TestExample` instance. Once the fixture gets the class scope, assigning to instance attributes doesn't work anymore - the `setup()` and `test_foo()` are called on different `TestExample` instances. Resort to explicit class-scoped attributes, e.g.

```
class TestExample:
    b = 1.0

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup(self, fixture_a):
        self.__class__.c = self.b * fixture_a
```

or

```
class TestExample:
    b = 1.0

    @staticmethod
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup(fixture_a):
        TestExample.c = TestExample.b * fixture_a
```

or

```
class TestExample:
    b = 1.0

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup(self, request, fixture_a):
        request.cls.c = request.cls.b * fixture_a
```

The last example shows that a class-scoped fixture is not required to be part of the test class:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def setup_cls(request, fixture_a):
    request.cls.c = request.cls.b * fixture_a


class TestExample:
    b = 1.0

    ...
```

Comment: @hoefling these all work thank you. which method do you prefer and why?

Comment: @tallwithknees I think I would start with either the first or the second since better readable, and if it needs to be reused in different test classes later, refactor the fixture to the one in the last example.